# Can't find a unistd.h with uuid_t typedef

Tags: c, perl, sdk, vmware

Trying to build vSphere Perl SDK on Centos 2.6. Got all dependencies except one, namely UUID-0.05.

The problem seems to be that the uuid.h include file references unistd.h for the definition of uuid_t, but unistd.h has no such thing. Worse, though some people have described a conflict between the two include files for the variable, I cannot find a unistd.h file on the Internet with the definition.

Can someone point to such a unistd.h file?  Or, even, a better approach to take?

Here's some info about the original issue:

In Changelog for uuid.1.6.2:

o Apply workaround to uuid.h to avoid conflicts with
     vendor UUID implementations where uuid_t (Darwin/MacOSX)
     or uuid_create/uuid_compare (POSIX) might exist.
     [Ralf S. Engelschall]

In uuid.h:

```
/* workaround conflicts with system headers */
#define uuid_t       __vendor_uuid_t
#define uuid_create  __vendor_uuid_create
#define uuid_compare __vendor_uuid_compare
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#undef  uuid_t
#undef  uuid_create
#undef  uuid_compare
```

Here's the original problem (compiling):

```
jloiacon@flowviewerprime /home/jloiacon/UUID-0.05 249 >make
cp UUID.pm blib/lib/UUID.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/typemap  UUID.xs > UUID.xsc && mv UUID.xsc UUID.c
gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"0.05\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.05\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE"   UUID.c
UUID.xs: In function âdo_generateâ:
UUID.xs:13: error: storage size of âuuidâ isnât known
UUID.xs:14: warning: implicit declaration of function âuuid_generateâ
UUID.xs:13: warning: unused variable âuuidâ
UUID.xs: In function âdo_unparseâ:
UUID.xs:20: error: storage size of âuuidâ isnât known
UUID.xs:23: warning: implicit declaration of function âuuid_unparseâ
UUID.xs:20: warning: unused variable âuuidâ
UUID.xs: In function âdo_parseâ:
UUID.xs:29: error: storage size of âuuidâ isnât known
UUID.xs:33: warning: implicit declaration of function âuuid_parseâ
UUID.xs:30: warning: unused variable âstrâ
UUID.xs:29: warning: unused variable âuuidâ
make: *** [UUID.o] Error 1
```

Thanks

Comment: `uuid.h` **is** included by the sources not compiling?

Comment: Yes. uuid.h is included and is accessed. But the first thing that include does is include another file, unistd.h, which is supposed to have a more machine-specific typedef for uuid_t, but my unistd.h file does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

[Install `uuid-c++-devel`.](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=80141)

lorem ipsum